# media queries not being picked up in IE8 with only screen

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet, media-queries

I am performing some testing on IE8 and I am finding that my media queries are not being picked up by the browser. In the example below, the `.telephone` class is always being picked up as the second class declaration and not the first one, with the margin-bottom.

I can't see what the reason for this would be as the site that my site is based on works correctly on IE8.

I know the window is definitely larger than 640px.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/inc/css/style.css" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/inc/css/index.css" />           

@media only screen and (min-width:640px) {
    .telephone {
        padding-top:.75em;
            margin-bottom:.5em
    }
}

.telephone {
    display:block;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1;
    padding-top:.5em
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen media queries based on screen width are a CSS3 feature that are supported starting at IE9. IE8 and below will not see them because they do not support the feature. [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) reference for media queries.

You would need to use a JavaScript polyfill, such as [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), or if you are using jQuery, you can [write your own function](http://www.venveo.com/articles/view/quick-tip-jquery-media-queries) that would act similarly. If not using jQuery, I believe you can do the same with normal JavaScript using a similar function where window.onload and window.onresize would be used instead of $(window).load() and $(window).resize(), and use window.innerWidth instead of $(window).width().

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was missing. I've added `respond` and `jRespond`.